# Streaming MP3 to Android from C# server

Tags: c#, java, android, tcp

I have set up a C# server which at present serves up one test mp3 file over TCP. The code to send the file is as follows

```
    public void RunStreamer()
    {
        log.MakeLog("Starting streamer");
        Run = true;
        //Need to look into how to thread this to not block the main window
        TcpListener listen = new TcpListener(localAddr, _port);
        listen.Start(); //startlistening to client requests

            //blocks until a client request comes in
        for (; ; )
        {
            Socket socket = listen.AcceptSocket();
            if (socket.Connected)
            {

                SendFileToClient(socket);
                socket.Disconnect(false);
            }
        }

    }

    void SendFileToClient(Socket socket)
    {
        log.MakeLog("Connection made");
        NetworkStream netStream = new NetworkStream(socket);
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(netStream);
        //Todo - set specfified file - this file just for test
        FileStream filestream = File.Open(@"C:\MusicTest\Test.mp3", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
        filestream.CopyTo(netStream);
        netStream.Flush();
        netStream.Close();


    }
```

In my test android set up I am making a call to the server on a button click:

```
    public void btngo_click(View v)
{
    final TcpClient client = new TcpClient();

    new Thread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            client.GetStream();
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                public void run()
                {
                     int length = client.GetLength();
                     if(length > 0)
                     {
                        byte[] result = client.GetResult();
                        try {
                            // create temp file that will hold byte array
                            File tempMp3 = File.createTempFile("test", "mp3", getCacheDir());
                            tempMp3.deleteOnExit();
                            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(tempMp3);
                            fos.write(result);
                            fos.close();


                            mediaPlayer.reset();

                            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(tempMp3);
                            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(fis.getFD());

                            mediaPlayer.prepare();
                            mediaPlayer.start();
                        } catch (IOException ex) {
                            String s = ex.toString();
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }

                     }
                }
            });

        }
    }).start();

}
```

the stream is received in the TcpClient class which is as follows:

```
public class TcpClient {

public final static String SERVER_ADDRESS = "127.0.0.1";
public final static int SERVER_PORT = 65000;
public String TotalResult;
public int Length;
byte[] result = new byte[21000000];


public TcpClient()
{



}

public int GetLength()
{
    return Length;  

}

public byte[] GetResult()
{

    return result;

}

public void GetStream()
{
    try
    {

        final Socket socket = new Socket("192.0.0.5", 85000);
        final InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        int nread;


        while((nread = input.read(result, 0, result.length)) != -1)
        {

            buffer.write(result, 0, nread);
        }
        buffer.flush();

        //input.read(result);
        Length = result.length;


        input.close();
        socket.close();

    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        String exc = e.getMessage();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        String exc2 = e.getMessage();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

With apologies for all the code here is my problem.

I am receiving the stream. The temp MP3 file is created and the media player starts.  I then only get a short snippet of the test MP3 file (which is a full song). It also jumps about a bit. The length is not the same and the section of the song played is different each time.

How do I receive the full file in a ordered way such that it will provide full play back of the song.

I have tried to route around for this and have an idea that I need to tell my client what file size it should suspect and then perform some loop until all data is received although I have no idea how to successfully implement this if that is the correct solution.

Any pointers on where I am going wrong or what I can do to rectify would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: I assume this is via wi-fi?

Comment: Yes this is over wi-fi - I have tested in emulator on desktop and on phone with same results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having received no answers on this I dug around a bit more. Two things were wrong:
Firstly I had not included the size of the stream as a int sized header in my stream. I understand that for smaller files this will not be a problem but as file sizes grow it is necessary to make sure that the whole stream has been received.

This in turn raised another issue. The int I was sending as byte[] form c# was not returning the correct value in Java. Turns out Java uses sbytes -128 to 127 range as opposed to byte. This then involved a bit of code to convert to an int. then I could instruct the reader to readfully passing in the byte[] buffer with the actual size of the expected stream = voila it worked. MP3 files is received and plays just fine.